# Intent.getExtra gives nullPointerException

Tags: java, android

In one class I have this:

```
Double iso1 = 0.0;
final Intent start = new Intent(IsoAbun.this, IsoAbunCal.class);
start.putExtra("iso1", iso1);
startActivity(start);
```

Then in the other class I have this:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
Double iiso1 = 0.0;
iiso1 = Double.parseDouble(b.getString("iso1"));
```

All that gives a nullPointerException. The code seems fine to me, so is there anything I am missing, or is more information required?

Comment: should you be considering accepting my answer? :)

Comment: @Spurdow I'm testing this answer, will try to get back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `b.getDouble(key)`

hope it helps :)